# Trying to add 'group of fields' with 'add more' in drupal in a custom module form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have been trying writing a custom module in drupal 7 with a form to have a group of fields with 'add more' option as in 'Field Collection'(don't want to use module but write the code for control). I tried to find a good example but no success. Can anybody suggest how to proceed? Plz!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$form['education']['languages'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Languages'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="div_languages-fieldset-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['language_num']; $i++) 
    {   
        $form['education']['languages'][$i]['labels'] = array(
            '#prefix' => '<h1 id = "stu_form_label">',
            '#type' => 'item',
            '#title' => t('Form :'.($i+1)),
            '#suffix' => '</h1>',
        );

        // Language Drop down box
        $option_language = _get_language_mstr();
        $form['education']['languages'][$i]['language'] = array(
            '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline bottom_space languages_drop_down">',
            '#options' => $option_language,
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Language'),
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );

        // Level Drop down box
        $option_Level = _get_level_mstr();
        $form['education']['languages'][$i]['level'] = array(
            '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline bottom_space languages_drop_down">',
            '#options' => $option_Level,
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Level'),
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );  
    }
    if ($form_state['language_num'] > 1) 
    {
        $form['education']['languages']['remove_name'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Remove last language'),
            '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
            '#submit' => array('remove_one_language'),              
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'add_more_callback_language',
                'wrapper' => 'div_languages-fieldset-wrapper',
            ),
        );
    }

    $form['education']['languages']['add_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Add language'),
        '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
        '#submit' => array('add_one_language'),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'add_more_callback_language',
            'wrapper' => 'div_languages-fieldset-wrapper',
        ),
    );
    function add_more_callback_language($form, $form_state) {
       return $form['education']['languages'];
     }`
```

Try this method

Sample Link: [URL](http://nexumus.de/en/student/registration)

Click the tab **education**

Comment: Thanks for your help Vinox. But unfortunately I am unable to save the new added content. Can you please suggest?

Comment: I cannot do this either. Anyone can help with this?